# jquery is not refreshing the function

Tags: jquery

I have a jquery function  that suppose to delete last dynamic created div 
it delete first time but when I try to delete again it's giving me

Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'null' is null or not an object

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery("btnDeleteALineButton").click(function(e){
    var lineCount = GetServiceLineCount();
    if(lineCount > 0 ){
      $('ctrlServiceLine'+lineCount).remove();
      lineCount = lineCount -1;
    }
    //e.preventDefault()
  });
</script>
```

When I put alert I see that firt time give lineCount correct but never do -1

can some one please help me

Comment: Why are you using `$` and `jQuery` together like that?

Comment: some if i use $("btnDeleteALineButton").click(function(e){

Comment: if I'm reading this right it looks like the error is in the `GetServiceLineCount()` function, that is where you would be trying to get the property at. it is trying to set a property to the var ` lineCount` that is null.

Comment: serviceLineCount is in js file

Comment: var serviceLineCount=0   function GetServiceLineCount(){return serviceLineCount;}

Comment: so how to get the count of dynamic created div's and delete last one

Answer (score 1):

Your button selector is incorrect. If you are targeting id, change ("btnDeleteALineButton") to ("#btnDeleteALineButton"). For class use (".btnDeleteALineButton")

The same applies for the second selector.

Comment: @jay, Show us the code, and we can let you know. We need JS and html. Create a http://jsfiddle.net/ if possible. But first fix your selectors.

Answer (score 0):

Linecount is just a local variable inside the function. GetServiceLineCount() is always returning the same number.

Comment: so how to refresh to get   lineCount-1

Comment: What is the GetServiceLineCount() function doing?

Comment: it is just counting the dynamic created div

Comment: It would be better to see some actual code... Please edit your original post.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put 
     var lineCount = GetServiceLineCount(); 
into jquery initialization so that lineCount becomes global variable